# React Native setState

Tags: reactjs, react-native, pusher

I am trying to change my state from the render function but it does not work.

```
render() {
    return (
        <View>
            // some code

            {this._renderModal()}
        </View>
    )
}

_renderModal() {
        let channel = this.props.pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
        channel.bind('my-event', data => {
            this.setState({
                requestedToEnter: false
            });
            this.props.navigation.getNavigator('root').push(Router.getRoute('order', { restaurant_id }));
        });

        return (
            <Modal
                animationType={'slide'}
                transparent={false}
                visible={this.state.requestedToEnter}
                onRequestClose={this._handleEnter}>

                // some components
            </Modal>
        )
}
```

When I receive the *my-event* on *my-channel* it fires the function that is bind to it. The `setState` method does not change the state (or it does but do not re-render the component). I think it's because I am using the `setState` method in the event function.. How I can close the `Modal` when I receive an event from pusher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bad practice to call this.setState function in your render() as each time setState is called, the component will render itself with the updated state values binding to your components / subcomponents.

Alternatively, you can create a state variable

```
this.state = {
  isModalOpen: true
}
```

And put your pusher event listener in componentDidMount() and update your state variable value in the callback. Then, control your modal component visibility with the state variable:

```
<Modal
  animationType={'slide'}
  transparent={false}
  visible={this.state.isModalOpen}></Modal>
```